# Tax in Michigan

Tags: alcohol, tax-law

I live in Michigan and recently went to this new local bar where I was charged tax on my $3 beer. So total was $3.18. Is that illegal

Comment: why would that be illegal? welcome to the USA where the price isn't the price.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, that would be legal, indeed required

According to the [Michigan Dept of the Treasury](https://www.michigan.gov/taxes/0,4676,7-238-43519_43529-154427--,00.html):

> Individuals or businesses that sell tangible personal property to the final consumer are required to remit a 6% sales tax on the total price (including shipping and handling charges) of their taxable retail sales to the State of Michigan. Sales of electricity, natural or artificial gas and home heating fuels for residential use are taxed at a 4% rate. Michigan does not allow city or local units to impose sales tax.

According to the official Michigan [State Sales Tax Handbook](https://www.salestaxhandbook.com/michigan/sales-tax-exemptions)

Groceries and Prescription Drugs are exempt from sales tax, but prepared food is not. This includes restaurant food, and would, I think, include drinks served in a bar. When I worked in a Michigan restaurant and bar about 40 years ago, sales tax was charged, to the best of my memory.